# Get the R matrix from QR object

Tags: c++, r, matrix, eigen

I have the following `R` code

```
P <- matrix(...)
qrP <- qr(t(P))
qR <- qr.R(qrP)
```

where `P` is given as input.

I am trying to write the same code in `C++` by using Eigen:

```
auto qrP = P.transpose().fullPivHouseholderQr();
auto qr = qrP.matrixQR().template triangularView<Upper>();
```

But the problem is that the matrices are different (`R` vs `C++`). Am I computing the `qr` matrix in a wrong way?

This is what I get when I print the `qR` diagonals:

```
diag(qR)
# -1.0000000 -2.1718017 -0.4788378  0.0000000  0.0000000

cout << qr.diagonal();
// -370.247 1.37452 1 -1.5099e-14 -1.16018e-14
```

Comment: What matrix are you testing?

Comment: @harre where can I post the matrix? it's quite big.

Comment: Can you demonstrate the problem with a small matrix?

Comment: Note that the QR-implementation of LAPACK (used by R) and Eigen might differ.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg How? I do not think so.

Comment: @harre Please see my edit, can they be so different and produce this result?

Comment: Perhaps generate a random matrix with the same properties (e.g. does the matrix P have full rank?), so we can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Eigen version, you are using the QR factorization with full pivoting, whereas R calls Lapack's `DGEQP3` routines which corresponds to QR with column pivoting. In Eigen it is available through the `colPivHouseholderQr` method or `ColPivHouseholderQR` class.

Moreover, you are partly misusing the `auto` keyword here. Please see this [note](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html). A safer and closer to `R` implementation would thus be:

```
ColPivHouseholderQR<MatrixXd> qrT(T.transpose());
MatrixXd q = qrT.matrixQR().triangularView<Upper>();
std::cout << q.diagonal().transpose() << std::endl;
```

Comment: By using `colPivHouseholderQr`  I get the following diagonal `-370.247 -1.37452        1        0        0`. Do you have any idea why the results are so different? The input matrix `P` is "almost" the same (differences appear only after the third decimal).

Comment: Is the matrix rank deficient?

Comment: @harre How can I know if the matrix rank is deficient?

Comment: The matrix is clearly rank deficient because of the last two zeros on the diagonal. The difference is indeed very large. Make sure that you are really feeding both Eigen and R with the exact same numbers, and perhaps you could share the input matrix entries so that everybody can have a look.